# Sequelize ts: How to set foreign key value

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I need that when registering the user, the account should also be created automatically and I managed to do this using sequelize hooks, but the accountId I am not able to insert its value automatically and it always has a null value, I need that when the accountId has the id of Account, but I don't know how to do that

My models

```
import { Model, DECIMAL, INTEGER } from 'sequelize';
import db from '.';

class Account extends Model {
  id!: number;
  balance!: number;
};

Account.init({
  id: {
    type: INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  balance: {
    type: DECIMAL(13, 2),
    allowNull: false
  },
  },
  {
    sequelize: db,
    modelName: 'accounts',
    timestamps: false,
    underscored: true,
  },
);

export default Account;
```

```
import { Model, STRING, INTEGER } from 'sequelize';
import db from '.';
import Account from './account';

class User extends Model {
  id!: number;
  username!: string;
  password!: string;
  accountId!: any;
};

User.init({
  id: {
    type: INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },
  username: {
    type: STRING(50),
    allowNull: false,
  },
  password: {
    type: STRING(200),
    allowNull: false,
  },
  accountId: {
    type: INTEGER,
    // allowNull: false,
  },
  },
  {
    sequelize: db,
    modelName: 'users',
    tableName: 'users',
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false,
    underscored: true,
    hooks: {
      afterCreate(user, _op) {
        Account.create({ balance: 100})
      }
    },
  }
);

Account.hasOne(User, {foreignKey: 'id', as: 'accountId'});
User.belongsTo(Account, {foreignKey: 'accountId', as: 'idAccount'});

export default User;
```

My migrations

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('users', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      username: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
      },
      password: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING(200),
      },
      account_id: {
        // allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        references: {
          model: 'accounts',
          key: 'id',
        },
      },
    });
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, _Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('users');
  },
};
```

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('accounts', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      balance: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(13,2),
      },
    });
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, _Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('accounts');
  },
};
```

```
register = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const registerUser = await this.userController.register({username, password});

    res.status(200).json({registerUser});
  }
```

I've tried going through the hooks and inserting auto increment as well

Comment: I don't see that you wait for `Account.create({ balance: 100})` using `await`. Using it you can get a newly created account instance along with generated id

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).